# Keep getting a 401 error when trying to pull data

Tags: python, api

I'm fairly new to using web APIs and pulling data and i'm also pretty new with python. My goal is to make a stat-tracker app but I keep getting a 401 when I try and pull the data.

I've printed out the entire url just to make sure I didn't get it wrong. I copied and pasted the API key exactly so that shouldn't be a problem

```
 api_token = 'api key in python file'
 api_url_base = 'https://public-api.tracker.gg/v2/apex/standard/'
 headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
             'Authorization' : 'Bearer {}'.format(api_token)}

 def get_player_profile():

     api_url = '{}profile/psn/Daltoosh'.format(api_url_base)
     response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

     if response.status_code == 200:
         return json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
     else:
         return response.status_code, api_url

 print(get_player_profile())

 #player_profile = get_player_profile()

 #if player_profile is not None:
  #   print("Career Stats:")
   #  for k, v in player_profile['profile/psn/Daltoosh'].items():
    #     print('{0}:{1}.format(k, v)')

 #else:
  #   print('[!] Data Request Failed [!]')
```

I expected a status code of 200 but there seems to be a problem authenticating.

Comment: What does `response.text` say?

Comment: @MichaelKolber Its saying that no API key is found in the request

Comment: Can you please post a link to the documentation? I don't see anything about bearer tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too well versed in the web API that you are using, but I think you might be using the API token incorrectly. I don't think that specific API requires a Bearer token, but instead a separate header called `TRN-Api-Key`.

So maybe write something like this:

```py
headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'TRN-Api-Key' : api_token}
```

If you look [here](https://tracker.gg/developers/docs/authentication), you should be able to read up on how to set up authentication.

Comment: Seemed to work! I saw that but did not realise that prefix was something that was required